# How to map only every second value in array

Tags: javascript, arrays, dictionary, filter

I have some array of numbers:

```
var arr = [1, 7, 1, 4];
```

I want to increase only every first value, such that the expected output would be: `[2, 7, 2, 4]`

I tried some combination of `map` and `filter` but I don't understand how it can work together...

```
var mapuj = arr.map(x => x *2);
```

Comment: you can use indexing for this purpose like this **arr[0] = arr[0]*2**

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use `map()` and use second argument which is idnex to determine if it's at event index or not

```js
 let arr = [1, 7, 1, 4];
 
 let output = arr.map((n, index) => index % 2 === 0 ? n * 2 : n);
 
 console.log(output);
```